# Writing simple du clone. Getting random values for filesizes in subdirectories.

Tags: c, recursion, sum, filesize, directory

I am trying to write a basic program that will sum up the filesizes of all files in the current directory and all subdirectories. I thought it would be a nice exercise. I am trying to use basic recursion for this. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

long totalbytes = 0;

long dirsize(const char* directory, int verbose)
{
  struct dirent *de;
  struct stat s;
  DIR * dir; 
  //long total_items = 0;
  long filesize = 0;

  dir = opendir(directory);
  if (dir == NULL)
  {
     printf("Failed to open %s.\n", directory);
     return -1;
  }

  while ((de = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
  {
    stat(de->d_name, &s);
  if (S_ISLNK(s.st_mode)) 
  {
    printf("links are ignored.\n");
  }
  if (de->d_type == DT_REG)
  {
    filesize = 0; //be sure to reset this each time to avoid inaccuracy
    stat(de->d_name, &s); // get file info into our s structure
    if (verbose) 
    {
      printf("%s/%s : %ld bytes (%f MB)\n", directory, de->d_name, s.st_size, (float) s.st_size / 1024 / 1024);
    }
    filesize = s.st_size; //put file size into filesize variable
    totalbytes += filesize; //increment totalbytes
  }
  if (de->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0)
  {
    char pathname[PATH_MAX];
    sprintf(pathname, "%s/%s", directory, de->d_name);
    dirsize(pathname, verbose); //recursion: keep looping until no more subdirs remain
    }
  }
  closedir(dir);
  return totalbytes;
}

long compute_size(const char* directory, int verbose)
{
  long space = dirsize(directory, verbose);
  return space;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: dirsize DIRECTORY\n");
return -1;
  }

  int verbose = 1; //show or hide individual computations

  long space = compute_size(argv[1], verbose);
  if (space != -1)
  {
    float space_mb = (float) space / 1024 / 1024;
    printf("space occupied: %ld bytes\n", space);
    printf("(%f MB)\n", space_mb);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my program output (I am also including an ls of the subdirectory)

```
08:35 PM@~/tmp$ ./dirsize .
./dirsize : 8369 bytes (0.007981 MB)
./diskstat.c : 1430 bytes (0.001364 MB)
./diskstat : 7993 bytes (0.007623 MB)
./ftw.c : 491 bytes (0.000468 MB)
./a.out : 8044 bytes (0.007671 MB)
./arrays.sh : 212 bytes (0.000202 MB)
./fileread/timestamp : 0 bytes (0.000000 MB)
./fileread/timestamp.c : 0 bytes (0.000000 MB)
./fileread/a.out : 8044 bytes (0.007671 MB)
./fileread/build.prop : 8044 bytes (0.007671 MB)
./fileread/read.c : 4096 bytes (0.003906 MB)
./fileread/read : 454656 bytes (0.433594 MB)
./local.fstab : 76 bytes (0.000072 MB)
./dirsize.c : 1857 bytes (0.001771 MB)
./echo.sh : 223 bytes (0.000213 MB)
./TEAMS.sh : 605 bytes (0.000577 MB)
space occupied: 504140 bytes
(0.480785 MB)
08:35 PM@~/tmp$ ls -l fileread/
total 40
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raidzero raidzero 8132 Dec 28 10:39 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 raidzero raidzero 2346 Dec 28 10:09 build.prop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raidzero raidzero 8384 Dec 29 13:57 read
-rw-r--r-- 1 raidzero raidzero 1150 Dec 28 10:16 read.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raidzero raidzero 8132 Dec 29 13:57 timestamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 raidzero raidzero  659 Dec 28 10:39 timestamp.c
08:35 PM@~/tmp$
```

In my limited experience, getting random data is  sign of improper memory allocation, but st_size in the stat struct is a long int..?

Comment: Look at [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) to make some parts of your job simpler.

Comment: Note that `stat(de->d_name, &s); if (S_ISLNK(s.st_mode))` will never spot a symlink; you have to use `lstat()` to see a link as a link.  (`stat()` follows the symlink to its bitter end; `lstat()` tells that the entry is a symlink if it is, and otherwise behaves like `stat()`.

Comment: It would probably be sensible to use `snprintf()` to combine the directory and file name; that prevents buffer overflows.  Of course, you also need to check whether the copying was complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`de->d_name` only has the filename - it does not contain the path leading up to it. So you're statting `./timestamp` rather than `./fileread/timestamp`, for example. You can either construct the full path to the file, use `chdir()` to enter directories as you go (not safe if you're in a multi-threaded environment, and can be fragile if dirs are moved when you're in them - [`fchdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fchdir) can be very helpful to get back to higher directories), or (on recent unixen) use the [`openat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat)/[`fstat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) functions to traverse directories.

Note that, had you checked for error returns from `stat`, you would have noticed this. Always check those error returns.

Comment: I used sprintf to construct the path to the file though here: `sprintf(pathname, "%s/%s", directory, de->d_name);` (at least that was my intention)

Comment: @raidzero, you do this when you recurse into subdirectories, but you call stat on the raw `de->d_name` value

Comment: ah I see what you mean! I only built the pathname for entering directories!

Comment: @raidzero Glad I could help :) Don't forget to click the checkmark to mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: @raidzero: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Note that the conventional way to say "thanks" around here is by upvoting the helpful answers, and by accepting the most helpful answer.  At this stage, there are some limits on what you can do, but you can always accept the most helpful answer - which would be this one since (a) it helped you solve the problem and (b) it's the only answer.